# Why are cockpit alarms still so distracting and unable to be silenced?

Tags: air-traffic-control, emergency, cockpit-alerts

I'm watching video [RV 10 N783V My 1st Emergency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZPDfZArP_Q)

At 8:45 [a stall alarm goes off](https://youtu.be/lZPDfZArP_Q?t=530) and is a horrible piercing whistle. Why? Surely the pilot has enough distractions without also being deafened while trying to talk to ATC.

Isn't there a better way of indicating a continuing alert, and why can't pilots switch the the thing off when they need to?

---

EDIT: The video shows that it is a **false-positive** warning. The pilot eventually manages to switch it off by resetting all his electronics.

Comment: @ymb1 While I think it may be relevant if the OP were asking about this specific situation, it seems the OP is more interested in why they can't be turned off.

Comment: I never liked the gear horn in the CRJs (Rockwell Collins GPWS). It sounds exactly like the old steady dual frequency tone you got on TV stations when they went off the air overnight.  I found that particular sound very easy to blend into background when under some high stress situation in the sim.  The saving grace was you'd get "Too Low - Gear" if you ignored the warning horn because you were saturated with crises and got too close the ground.

Comment: "...while trying to talk to ATC". In a situation with a stall warning, talking to ATC should be the LAST priority. Aviate - Navigate - Communicate. A stall warning should absolutely override the radio.

Comment: @quietflyer How can you be sure it's a false alert? AF447 comes to mind

Comment: For those that didn't watch the video, the stall warning was caused by an iced-over pitot tube, supposedly.  The pilot realized he wasn't stalling before he realized the icing condition.  Not sure how the stall warning actually works on this aircraft - the pilot also mentioned the aoa indicator not working.  Would that have separate icing protection?  Or is it somehow driven from the pitot tube, by factoring in the g-loading?

Comment: Because [the opposite problem can be far worse](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/61605/21128)

Comment: ATC hearing the stall alarm surely can react in dealing the situation with respect to surrounding traffic.

Comment: If you can't focus through a stall alarm then perhaps...

Comment: Alarm: "Stall Warning!  Stall Warning!!".  Pilot: *hits snooze*.

Answer (score 41):

A stall condition needs to be handled **now**, and once it's handled, the alarm will go away. What you don't want to happen is you are in an approaching stall condition, the pilot hits a "silence" button while the situation gets worse without the plane telling them.

An emergency is "AVIATE, NAVIGATE, COMMUNICATE" in that order. Fly the plane first, point it where you want to go second, and third, only if you have time/resources, is to talk to ATC about it. The pilot should be fixing the problem first, focus on flying the plane, ATC can wait.

They can't be turned off for that reason. Deal with the problem and the alarm goes away, you don't want to silence the alarm and forget about it. There is some merit to "overloading", where multiple alarms are happening at the same time, or when the pilot focuses on a low priority item and forgets to fly the airplane ([Eastern Air 401](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Air_Lines_Flight_401)).

Comment: "AVIATE, NAVIGATE, COMMUNICATE" -  All the time, not just in emergencies.

Comment: "Deal with the problem and the alarm goes away" was unfortunately part of the accident chain for AF447, as in that accident, the alarm went away while the problem was being made worse, due to very low airspeed, while it started sounding again when the crew dealt with the problem and the airspeed began to increase. But that goes to show how ingrained "deal with the problem and the alarm goes away" is, to the point the crew continued to exacerbate the situation, perhaps because making the problem worse did happen to silence the alarm.

Comment: @ZachLipton I would trust the airplane tech way longer than any human - and so did the pilots. It was the wrong call in this situation, but how many accidents would happen, if there were no tech and only humans to fly the plane?

Comment: @ZachLipton the issue is dealing *correctly* with the problem, not a general rant on doing things just to turn off alarms :)

Answer (score 19):

Things may be different for small airplanes, but for the transport-category, i.e. Part 25 certification, your concern is taken into account:*

> (d) The alert function must be designed to minimize the effects of
> false and nuisance alerts. In particular, it must be designed to:
>
> ...
>
> (2) Provide a means to suppress an attention-getting component of an
> alert caused by a failure of the alerting function that interferes
> with the flightcrew's ability to safely operate the airplane. This
> means must not be readily available to the flightcrew so that it could
> be operated inadvertently or by habitual reflexive action. When an
> alert is suppressed, there must be a clear and unmistakable
> annunciation to the flightcrew that the alert has been suppressed.
>
> — [14 CFR § 25.1322 - Flightcrew alerting](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.1322).

As the text shows, suppressing alerts must **not** be readily available, but the means to suppress must be provided – once the crew for example confirms the false-positive. In the linked video the pilot reset a few circuit breakers and the warning was gone.

---

* Thanks to @Gerry for his insight and @Bianfable for tracking down the [similar European rule](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/86756/14897), that regulation applies to aircraft made [since 2011](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFinalRule.nsf/ce5d1d75020744f7862575d8006bb600/5b78af7618a94c33862577cf0049338b!OpenDocument). It may be worth mentioning that at least the Airbus A320 have had the ability to suppress spurious alerts since the mid-80s.

Comment: This version of the rule, [Amdt. 25-131, Eff. 1/3/2011](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFinalRule.nsf/ce5d1d75020744f7862575d8006bb600/5b78af7618a94c33862577cf0049338b!OpenDocument) was first applied to the B787 as Special Conditions and then codified in 2011. Prior to that (Amdt. 25-38, Eff. 2/1/77) 25.1322 only specified the color of 'Warning, caution, and advisory lights'. So the rule you reference only applies to new and relatively recent Part 25 aircraft. See the link for the explanations.

Comment: As a non-pilot, I'm wondering if the alarm should have come back on after resetting the circuit breaker - his pitot tube was still frozen up at that point, he still hadn't figured out to turn on the heating for it. Why _did_ it not come back on? (Also, why is there no hygrometer/thermometer combo inside a/that pitot tube?)

Comment: @Sixtyfive: My analysis: when the airspeed dropped on its way to an invalid reading, this triggered the digital stall warning. When the system was rebooted, there was no speed reading to use for the stall algorithm (this is worthy of its own question BTW). More complex aircraft have ice detectors, but temperature alone would not be a good indicator; altitude and visible moisture come into play (again, very valid question worthy of more visibility).

Comment: If you want more insight to the Flightcrew Alerting rule and what is acceptable, I suggest reading [AC 25.1322-1](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_25.1322-1.pdf). It provide examples on how to categorize alerts and how they should be presented.

Answer (score 5):

**A Stall horn will tell you, you are (close to) no longer flying, but actually falling.**

Since this is of paramount importance for every airplane, it will sound until recovery is completed. Often it is only the silencing of the stall horn that can give a pilot certainty about that. Sometimes even this is ignored, because pilots treat it as just as alarming as any other device, which it isn't. Gear malfunction, terrain alert, traffic alert, burning engine,  a hijacker holding you at gun point, all these things are of minor importance compared to a stall.

As dictated by law, a stall horn works on every winged aircraft, even if all power is lost and all other instruments are dead. (EDIT: this is not correct. It should be, but it ain't. See comments)

A winged aircraft with a continuously sounding stall horn is in the process of crashing. It is not going there, it is there. Its falling, like a brick.

Tell me, why would anybody in his right mind ever want to even just be able to shut that down?

Comment: *"As dictated by law, a stall horn works on every winged aircraft"* I've flown aircraft without stall horns, they are not dictated by law (usually you find this in retractable gear aircraft where the stall horn can be mistaken for the gear horn). What *is* required by law is an *indication*, which can be a pronounced aerodynamic indication  **or** a horn (but a light is not allowed by itself).

Comment: *"Tell me, why would anybody in his right mind ever want to even just be able to shut that down?"* Because, as indicated and shown in the video, the pilot discovered it was a false indication. Also because it was an unpleasant continuous whine that lasted for minutes.

Comment: @Ron Beyer The reason why stall horns are called "horns" and not "alarm" or "indicator" is because of the simplicity of their construction. They are not just activated by a stall, they are actually powered by it. As far as I know,  true stall horns or an equivalent with a comparable reliability are mandatory in all certified winged aircraft. Whether they are mandatory in powered gliders, rotor planes or experimental aircraft I admit I do not know.  My bad

Comment: @chasly-supports Monica- False indication and unpleasant noise are to my opinion bad reasons for silencing a signal that tells me I am not flying. An astounding number of crashes in history could have been prevented, had only the pilot understood the severity of a stall indication. Properly maintained traditional stall horns extremely seldom malfunction. Besides, I rather listen to hours of stall horn blowing in my ear, than crashing my aircraft. Crashing is very bad. Very bad is worse than annoying.

Comment: @Berend *"As far as I know, true stall horns or an equivalent with a comparable reliability are mandatory in all certified winged aircraft"*... That's the false part. I know what a stall "horn" is and how it works, see [CFR 25.207(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.207). An audible device is **not** required for "other than transport category aircraft". It absolutely did not exist in the RG PA-24-180 Comanchee I flew, a certified aircraft.

Comment: @Ron Beyer  I have a hard time finding the line saying: "An audible device is not required for "other than transport category aircraft" . What i find is "However, a visual stall warning device that requires the attention of the crew within the cockpit is not acceptable by itself." which to my understanding excludes everything but a stick shaker and an acoustic signal.

Comment: @Ron Beyer You flew more aircraft than I did obviously, so I guess you must be right, but I still wouldn't dream of switching it off in the planes I did fly. Admitting I never stalled other than on purpose at altitude during training, and hearing the stall horn on many occasions anyway, I can understand people may find that annoying, but I would never advice to silence it.

Comment: @Ron Beyer -While respectfully doing my home work on the "poor mans bonanza" I couldn't help noticing how the absence of a stall horn is mentioned  first as a general contributing factor in accidents in a number of references. So yes, you're right, scary so. Concerning 14 CFR § 25.207,  It somehow doesn't make sense to have this elaborate demand package to a device that isn't even mandatory.

Comment: @Berend : I've flown a few acrobatic-certified aircraft and none had a stall warning. Makes sense, as they often get into deliberate stalls and stall-like conditions, and they aren't used for long-distance travel anyway. Also in case of gliders, a stall horn doesn't make any sense, as gliders are flown at near-stall for extended time periods in a thermal. I haven't seen any in any glider I've been in.

Comment: @vsz The idea that stall horns are mandatory in all certified aircraft is something I got from my first instructor, who is a bit of an established expert, so I just took it for granted. Maybe he just tried to simplify things for me. He did emphasize the importance of a stall horn as more alarming than just about anything else stronger than any of his colleagues, which stuck with me.

Comment: @vsz Gliders are not flown at near stall in thermals, that would be both inefficient and dangerous. Gliders are flown at low airspeed in thermals. No glider I've flown had a stall horn. I'm sure that to a power pilot, thermalling speed in a glider would seem scarily close to stall.

Comment: @Neil_UK Some gliders do have an acoustic climb rate indicator, which does make distinct "Yoohoo! You are dropping like a brick !"-like  noises in a stall. My first ever glider flight turned into an "impossible turn" maneuver after the winch cable ripped. I could count the needles on the pine trees on the way in.  That was not silent.