# What are the differences between direct law and mechanical back-up?

Tags: flight-controls

I am learning for an avionics exam and I cannot find any differences between the direct law and the mechanical backup.

I will describe the laws that I learned such that it is easier to see if I have some misconceptions.

- **Normal law**: Standard mode of operation
- **Alternate law**: (at least two failures detected):

  - Loss of pitch and bank protection
  - $\alpha$-protection and high-speed protection replaced by stabilities
  - Load factor limitation is still active
- **Direct law**: (at least two failures second not self-detected)

  - All protections lost
  - Manual pitch trim
- **Mechanical back-up**: (all electric supply for control computers lost)

  - All protections lost
  - Manual pitch trim

> Is the only difference between the ***direct law*** and the ***mechanical***
>   ***back-up*** that we do not have operating computers for control?

Comment: feed back loop.

Comment: Yes. Mechanical backup on Airbus encompasses the mechanical links between trim/elevators and pedals/rudder. Laws are related to the joystick and flight control computers. See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/36271/3201) which should provide all the elements to answer the question.

Comment: The last line should be “Manual pitch trim *only*”, because only the trim wheels and rudder pedals have hydromechanical linkage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key piece of knowledge to understand a FBW system is that you need to differentiate between *signalling* and *actuation*.
*signalling* is what tells the control surface to move and to what position. In old airplanes, this was by steel wires. In FBW airplanes it's by copper wires carrying an electrical signal.
*actuation* is what actually moves the controls surfaces to the commanded position, the muscles. Traditionally this is hydraulics, but you can also find electric actuators these days.
For the Airbus, Normal, Alternate & Direct all use electrical signalling (whether produced by computers or not). But what to do if there's no electrics? That's Mechanical backup, where you have steel-wire signalling of specific surfaces.

Comment: Does Airbus have mech backup?

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz - see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/20963/how-are-fly-by-wire-airliners-controlled-in-case-of-complete-electrical-failure) and others like it here.

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz, the A320 does as does A330 and A340, but I had the impression that A380 does not.

Comment: Well, the important bit is that the side-stick is only connected to electric sensors, so in the mechanical backup mode it does nothing and only the trim wheels and rudder pedals work.