# What happens to ADIRU/FAC AP etc, when Pitot probes fail?

Tags: flight-controls, airbus-a320, flight-instruments, autopilot, bird-strike

**Situation**: Suppose due to a bird strike pitot 1 is blocked with debris and radome is dented causing inconsistent airspeed indication between P2 and P3 (due to unequal airflow). This happens at about FL50 before landing. Aircraft is A320 neo.

Will the ADIRU 1 be operational? Since only ADR 1 is failing due to blocked P1 and IR 1 is still functioning. Capt. lose his airspeed indication. He can switch to ADIRU 3 but inconsistency will be seen. What systems will fail due to this? How FAC respond? I think Autopilot will be out...

**Help**: Can anyone be explain what will happen in this scenario?

Comment: "*I think Autopilot will be out*", it will as airspeed is not reliable. A320 FCOM cited [here](https://www.pprune.org/tech-log/376433-af447-26.html): "*If one ADR is faulty, or has been rejected by the ELAC, and if there is a speed or alpha disagreement between the 2 remaining ADRs, alternate law becomes active, and protections are lost.*" There are more details in the forum linked. See [AF447 BEA report](https://bea.aero/docspa/2009/f-cp090601.en/pdf/f-cp090601.en.pdf), from *1.16.3.1 Analysis of the initial sequence*. See also [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36268/3201)